# Unable to implement Struts 2 token interceptor with hyperlink

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, token, interceptor

I  tried to implement token interceptor with the `<s:url ..` tag but its showing error on the first click. i.e.

> The form has already been processed or no token was supplied, please try again.

I want to implement this interceptor, because if users already deleted a row and refresh the page once again then the same action should not perform once again.

```xml
<s:url id="linkdelete" action="DeleteLatestUpload.action" namespace="/admin/insecure/upload">
     <s:param name="latestUploadId" value="latestUploadId"></s:param>
     <s:token name="token"></s:token>
</s:url> 
<a href='<s:property value="#linkdelete"/>' style="color: white;text-decoration:  none;" class="delbuttonlink">Clear current Uploads</a>
```

**and my `struts.xml`:**

```xml
 <action name="DeleteLatestUpload" class="v.esoft.actions.UploadExcel" method="deleteUploads">                   
     <interceptor-ref name="token"></interceptor-ref>
     <interceptor-ref name="basicStack"></interceptor-ref>  
     <result name="success" type="tiles"> uploadforward</result>
     <result name="invalid.token" type="tiles">uploadforward </result>
 </action>
```

Comment: Just do redirect after post. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get and http://struts.apache.org/development/2.x/docs/redirect-after-post.html.

Comment: @AleksandrM previously i was redirecting , but while redirecting i loosed the `<s:actionmessge/>` while redirecting.

Comment: For storing action messages there is `store` interceptor: http://struts.apache.org/development/2.x/docs/message-store-interceptor.html.

Comment: @AleksandrM thanks for that info, is the `store` interceptor is newly created in struts2?  Because , before 4 month ago, i did not heard the name of this interceptor

Comment: If you still want to use token in link then see my answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> The s:token tag merely places a hidden element that contains the
>   unique token.

There's not need to use token with url, because the form should be submitted. If you want to pass some token as a parameter then you need to use `s:param` tag.

Define the parameter

```
  private String token;

  public String getToken() {
    return token;
  }

  public void setToken(String token) {
    this.token = token;
  }

  public String execute() throws Exception {
    Map<String, Object> context = ActionContext.getContext().getValueStack().getContext();
    Object myToken = context.get("token");
    if (myToken == null) {
        myToken = TokenHelper.setToken("token");
        context.put("token", myToken);
    }
    token = myToken.toString();
    return SUCCESS;
  }
```

in the JSP

```
<s:url var="linkdelete" namespace="/admin/insecure/upload" action="DeleteLatestUpload" ><s:param name="struts.token.name" value="%{'token'}"/><s:param name="token" value="%{token}"/></s:url>
```

Comment: How?  did you mean that , i have to use `<s:param name="token" value="23424223"></s:param>` instead of  `<s:token name="token"></s:token>`  ?    , followed by rest of my above codes.   here  `23424223` is some unique number.

Comment: Tokens are implemented as `hidden` field which contain the value of the  the unique token. It's passed as parameter when you submit the form. if you don't submit it struts2 may not get it as a parameter.

Comment: can you modify my above code and implement it with the `s:param ..` ? as you said, let me see by watching your updates for full understanding.

Comment: Thanks for your support, though i have not tested your code but it looks cool. I will accept your answer once after testing & implementing this piece of code with my app.

Answer (score 5):

The most simple way to use token with url is to use `<s:token/>` tag to set token value into session and retrieve it in `<s:param>` tag.

```
<s:token/>

<s:url var="..." action="...">
  <s:param name="struts.token.name" value="'token'"/>
  <s:param name="token" value="#session['struts.tokens.token']"/>
</s:url>
```

Comment: @user2732367: And with this solution there is no need to define "special" token method in every action class.