# how to have per-session token value in struts2

Tags: struts2, csrf, interceptor

How can we have persistent token value(or Form Key) during the valid session in struts2?
When `<s:token/>` is in the forms, after submitting the form, the token's value gets changed. It causes this problem that users can not open 2 browser tab and work with them(Only one tab is active due to the tokens' unique value per form).
how can I solve this with struts2 and have durable token value **per session(Not per form)**?

> I think overriding the interceptor can solve the problem, but i wanna
>   to consider other options

Comment: What the purpose would be to have such a token?

Comment: @RomanC :It causes this problem that users can not open 2 browser tab and work with them(Only one tab is active due to the token's unique value per form)

Comment: It's not true, the token is generated per request.

Comment: @RomanC: that's right! So I don't want this mechanism! I want the token to be generated just once per session(Not per request)

Comment: bu you can't use a `s:token` tag in this case.

Comment: @RomanC: I think overriding the interceptor can solve the problem, but I wanna to consider other options

Comment: @RomanC: that's my question!

Comment: ok, while you are looking for other options see http://stackoverflow.com/a/18823084/573032

Comment: @RomanC: please look at my comment for coding_idiot's answer

Comment: Tokens are used primarily for solving double-submit-problem, and it also qualify for csrf prevention.

Answer (score 0):

`Don't use token at all`

If you require something per session, use the session itself. Token is meant to prevent request replay attacks. So just having one per session doesn't make sense.

Comment: Please look at this link:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10466241/new-csrf-token-per-request-or-not
and this chat:
http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10926/discussion-between-laurencei-and-zerkms
----
Conclusion: Per session tokens, prevent CSRF attacks. Isn't it right?

Comment: @AminSh This answer doesn't have a sense, may be it has a sense of humor but no more. OWASP has nothing against the per session token, but this token can't be used to prevent double submission.

Comment: The token per session can be an prevent CSRF and it must be something other than session id http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/22903/why-refresh-csrf-token-per-form-request ,  although the struts token seems to be best for double submission it can also be used as CSRF preventer.

Answer (score 0):

I also had same problem, in my functionality there is preview which opens in new tab. User can preview multiple times, so it was throwing a token exception. I got one code as at start of function I wrote :

```
String downloadTokenName = TokenHelper.getTokenName();
String downloadToken = TokenHelper.getToken(downloadTokenName);
```

At end of function in finally I reassign token value as :

```
TokenHelper.setSessionToken(downloadTokenName, downloadToken);
```

It solved my problem.