# How to pass a struts2 token via ajax without a form?

Tags: ajax, struts2, token, interceptor

I am trying to use the `token` interceptor that ships with Struts in order to implement a CSRF check. However instead of using a `<form />` I am making an AJAX call from within some JS:

**foo.jsp:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<%@ taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s" %>
<html>
<body>
    <s:token />
    <script>
        var strutsToken = "<s:property value="#session['struts.tokens.token']" />";
    </script>
    <script src="bar.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**bar.js:**

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/endpoint',
    data: strutsToken,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    cache: true,
    success: function() { console.log('success'); },
    error: function() { console.log('failure'); }
});
```

I've confirmed the token value is making it into the JS variable:

```
> strutsToken
"N3ZLLLR2Y3QGMZP0L3UCYWI5CO5NYZEY"
```

Unfortunately when that AJAX request is made an `invalid-token` error is thrown on the server.

Is what I am attempting to do possible and if so, how?

Comment: See my answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18822095/1700321.

Comment: Thanks, that pushed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is currently what is being requested by that [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) call:

```
GET /endpoint?N3ZLLLR2Y3QGMZP0L3UCYWI5CO5NYZEY
```

You need to give the token a parameter name. You also need to supply the "struts.token.name" parameter:

```
GET /endpoint?struts.token.name=token&token=N3ZLLLR2Y3QGMZP0L3UCYWI5CO5NYZEY
```

Now to make that work with the original code:

```js
var token = {
    "struts.token.name": "token",
    "token": strutsToken
};

$.ajax({
    url: '/endpoint',
    data: token,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    cache: true,
    success: function() { console.log('success'); },
    error: function() { console.log('failure'); }
});
```