# How to use Struts 2 token in JQuery Ajax?

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, jsp, struts2

How to use Struts2 token in jQuery Ajax?

Here is my sample code but it returns empty value.

```jsp
<body>
<s:token />
<script>
    var strutsToken = "<s:property value="#session['struts.tokens.token']" />";

    var token = {
        "struts.token.name": "token",
        "token": strutsToken
    };

    alert(token.token);
</script>

<s:if test="hasActionErrors()">
    <s:actionerror />
</s:if>
<br>
<s:form action="UpdateUser">
    <s:textfield name="name" label="User Name"></s:textfield>
    <s:textfield name="address" label="Address"></s:textfield>
    <s:submit name="submit" value="Update"></s:submit>
    <s:token />
</s:form>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18822095/1700321.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to generate a token before you make Ajax call.

> The s:token tag merely places a hidden element that contains the
> unique token.

You need to put this hidden element inside the form, so it to be included among other fields that are submitted. Check the usage of the [`<s:token>` tag](https://struts.apache.org/tag-developers/token-tag.html). If you want to make an Ajax call you can do it in many ways, so you can check this answer too for [Struts token interceptor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23518147/573032). One way is to use jQuery plugin and its [`<sj:submit>` tag](https://github.com/struts-community-plugins/struts2-jquery/wiki/SubmitTag).

```jsp
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="sj" uri="/struts-jquery-tags"%>
<html>
  <head>
    <sj:head/>
  </head>
  <body>

<s:form action="UpdateUser">
    <s:textfield name="name" label="User Name"></s:textfield>
    <s:textfield name="address" label="Address"></s:textfield>
    <sj:submit name="submit" value="Update"></s:submit>
    <s:token />
</s:form>
```