# How to provide protection against Cross Site Request Forgery (CSRF) attacks for an old web application built on Java and struts2 framework

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, csrf, struts

How to provide protection against Cross Site Request Forgery (CSRF) attacks for an old web application built on Java and struts2 framework?

Tried adding filter before servlet, stuck over there.

Answer (score 0):

Old application should use a [`token`](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/token-interceptor) or [`tokenSession`](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/token-session-interceptor) interceptor.

You can find details in my previous answer: [Struts2 token interceptor: CSRF protection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23518147/573032).